# Is the minimum value attained at an infinite number of points?

Tags: functions, derivatives, continuity, maxima-minima

[image]

I have solved the question, I just want to know whether my reasoning for the fourth option is correct or not.

As per the 4th option, the minimum value of $f$ is attained only at finite no. of points.

So can i say, the 4th option is false since there are infinite no. of points that gives the minimum value of $f$ i.e all the numbers in $ [-1,1] $ gives minimum value. And there are infinite points between them.

Is my reasoning correct?

Comment: Yes. That is correct.

Comment: Thanks a lot!!!

Answer (score 2):

As has already been stated in the comments, your result and reasoning are correct.